# COLAMD matrix reordering algorithm in MATLAB

Tags: matrices, permutations, numerical-linear-algebra, matlab, sparse-matrices

### Background

I'm dealing with some variable size square sparse matrices resulting from a FEM analysis, and my next step is optimizing the system solving in terms of speed. This is a visualization of some aspects of a typical matrix using MATLAB's [`spy`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spy.html):

[image: MATLAB visualization]

Please note I'm not using MATLAB (or this question would be useless), I just used it for generating the above graph.

The top left graph show my matrix as-is (non zero elements are blue), and bottom left shows the LU decomposition of said matrix.
On the top right I have applied the COLAMD algorithm (through MATLAB function [`colamd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colamd.html)) to generate a permutation to my matrix that would result in sparser LU factorized matrix, which indeed happens as the bottom right graph suggests (less than a third of the non zero elements I had before).

### Problem

Now my problem is understanding how to implement the COLAMD function by hand in the language I'm using. I've been browsing through the [COLAMD project page](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/colamd/), [read the paper on it](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/tr/DOC/REP-2000-397.pdf), and tried to [decypher the C source code](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/colamd/COLAMD/) to no avail.

What I'm looking for is an explanation of the algorithm in the likes of the ones provided by Rosetta Code ([example of an algorithm](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)), or some pseudo-code, basically anything that clearly shows what steps must be implemented.

---

I'm not sure if this belongs in Stack Overflow or here, please advise if it's in the wrong place. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the following paper

- Timothy A. Davis, John R. Gilbert, Stefan I. Larimore, Esmond G. Ng, [A column approximate minimum degree ordering algorithm](https://doi.org/10.1145/1024074.1024079), ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software, Volume 30, Issue 3.

the authors provided COLAMD preordering algorithm that relies on the same strategy of Matlab's COLMMD preordering algorithm,  but with a better heuristic ordering. Their algorithm is faster and produces better orderings, with less nonzeros in the factors of the matrix.

They used COLAMD for square unsymmetric matrices to provide a column preordering for sparse partial pivoting. The aim is to pick a column preordering relies only on the nonzero pattern $A$ such that the factorization stays as sparse as possible.

At step, say $l$, they pick a pivot column $v$ to minimize some metric on all the pivot columns as trial to decrease the fill. Then columns $v$ and $l$
are exchanged.